# ios This is taking longer than expected

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

```
/Users/Shared/sdk/flutter/bin/flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E266, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/Shared/sdk/flutter
    • Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (5 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
    • Engine revision ee76268252
    • Dart version 2.8.4

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/name/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.5, Build version 11E608c
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • DUB LX1                    • BVK6R19B14001142                     • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
    • iPhone SE (2nd generation) • DD315D38-1954-4A83-BE61-22A22547F47C • ios           • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-5 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone SE (2nd generation) in debug mode...
> Running Xcode build... Xcode build done.
> 463.9s Configuring the default Firebase app...
> *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350  1   libobjc.A.dylib
> 0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
> 0x00007fff23e3cd4c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188     3   Runner
> 0x000000010b418e72 +[FIRApp configure] + 130  4   Runner
> 0x000000010b98cf79 -[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin init] + 217  5   Runner
> 0x000000010b98cd86 +[FLTCloudFirestorePlugin registerWithRegistrar:] +
> 262   6   Runner                              0x000000010b3b4026
> +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 118  7   Runner                        <…> This is taking longer than expected...

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.5
  flutter_html: ^0.11.1
  cached_network_image: ^2.1.0+1
  url_launcher: ^5.4.5
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.11
  share: ^0.6.4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
  video_player: ^0.10.9+2
  visibility_detector: ^0.1.5
  youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.1
  awesome_dialog: ^0.1.4
  carousel_slider: ^2.1.0
  photo_view: ^0.9.2
  file_picker: ^1.9.0+1
  video_thumbnail: ^0.2.1
  firebase_storage: 3.0.4
  image_picker: ^0.6.6+1
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.14
  connectivity: ^0.4.8+6
  firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
```

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
> because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
> CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
> configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build
> configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

Comment: Isn't CocoaPods conflicting with the flutter iOS config?

Comment: i don no i am new in ios